# Why do inner block css transition effects parents text to be blured longer?

Tags: html, css

If i have some block with CSS tranformation transition and it has child with longer transition duration and other transform property text in the main block is blured till the child animation ends. Is there some way around it? Even when the other seperate block has its animation it blures the text, is there some way to seperate this effects?

```css
.parent {
  margin:10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  color: #aabb00;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.parent:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.05) ;
  -ms-transform: scale(1.05) ;
  -o-transform: scale(1.05) ;
  transform: scale(1.05) ;
}
.parent:hover .child {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) ;
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg) ;
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg) ;
  transform: rotate(360deg) ;
}

.child {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 1.5s;
  -ms-transition: all 1.5s;
  -o-transition: all 1.5s;
  transition: all 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
    <div>1234123412</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
    <div>1234123412</div>
</div>
```

Comment: when you scale the parent box it increases all elements inside the box, text too, that why it's showing you blurred

Comment: @Bhushan after animation the blur dissapiers, its chrome rendering issuу with aliasing, not a scale issue

Comment: I think this is a Webkit bug and is unavoidable...

Comment: @MiguelMorera its not like a bug, just webkit way of text rendering in transition, but is there really no way around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually its standard browser behavior to blur text on its resize, it comes from optimization easeus, to render new text not in every animation frame, but after animation ends. It cant be fixed.